# Kibana keeps complaining of dateparse and grokparse error

Tags: logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

I have the following in my logstash pipeline  (which receives multiline logs from Filebeat):

```
filter {
  if [type] == "oracle" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "(?<day>[A-Za-z]{3})(\s*)(?<month>[A-Za-z]{3})(\s*)(?<monthday>[0-9]{1,2})(\s*)(?<hour>[0-9]{1,2}):(?<min>[0-9]{1,2}):(?<sec>[0-9]{2})(\s*)(?<year>[0-9]{4})(\s*)%{GREEDYDATA:audit_message}" }
      add_tag => [ "oracle_audit" ]
    }
    grok {
      match => { "audit_message" => "ACTION :\[[0-9]*\] '(?<ora_audit_action>.*)'.*DATABASE USER:\[[0-9]*\] '(?<ora_audit_dbuser>.*)'.*PRIVILEGE :\[[0-9]*\] '(?<ora_audit_priv>.*)'.*CLIENT USER:\[[0-9]*\] '(?<ora_audit_osuser>.*)'.*CLIENT TERMINAL:\[[0-9]*\] '(?<ora_audit_term>.*)'.*STATUS:\[[0-9]*\] '(?<ora_audit_status>.*)'.*DBID:\[[0-9]*\] '(?<ora_audit_dbid>.*)'.*SESSIONID:\[[0-9]*\] '(?<ora_audit_sessionid>.*)'.*USERHOST:\[[0-9]*\] '(?<ora_audit_dbhost>.*)'.*CLIENT ADDRESS:\[[0-9]*\] '(?<ora_audit_clientaddr>.*)'.*ACTION NUMBER:\[[0-9]*\] '(?<ora_audit_actionnum>.*)'" }
    }
    grok {
      match => { "source" => [ ".*/[a-zA-Z0-9_#$]*_[a-z0-9]*_(?<ora_audit_derived_pid>[0-9]*)_[0-9]*\.aud" ] }
    }
    mutate {
      add_field => { "ts" => "%{year}-%{month}-%{monthday} %{hour}:%{min}:%{sec}" }
    }
    date {
      locale => "en"
      match => [ "ts", "YYYY-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss", "YYYY-MMM-d HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
    mutate {
      remove_field => [ "ts", "year", "month", "day" , "monthday", "hour", "min", "sec", "audit_message" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Sample log (coming from Filebeat and I can confirm they have been chunked correctly) :

```
Audit file /u01/app/oracle/admin/DEVINST/adump/DEVINST_ora_43619_20200913121607479069143795.aud
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
Build label:    RDBMS_12.2.0.1.0_LINUX.X64_170125
ORACLE_HOME:    /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1
System name:    Linux
Node name:      testserver
Release:        3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64
Version:        #1 SMP Fri Sep 21 09:07:21 UTC 2018
Machine:        x86_64
Instance name: DEVINST
Redo thread mounted by this instance: 1
Oracle process number: 55
Unix process pid: 43619, image: oracle@testserver (TNS V1-V3)

Sun Sep 13 12:16:07 2020 +00:00
LENGTH : '275'
ACTION :[7] 'CONNECT'
DATABASE USER:[1] '/'
PRIVILEGE :[6] 'SYSDBA'
CLIENT USER:[9] 'testuser'
CLIENT TERMINAL:[5] 'pts/0'
STATUS:[1] '0'
DBID:[10] '1762369616'
SESSIONID:[10] '4294967295'
USERHOST:[21] 'testserver'
CLIENT ADDRESS:[0] ''
ACTION NUMBER:[3] '100'
```

However although the logs went thru to Kibana, it is not showing me the "right" data, complaining of grokparse and dateparse error (even though the grok rule tested fine in the Kibana debugger!):

`Message` shown in Kibana:

```
Audit file /u01/app/oracle/admin/DEVINST/adump/DEVINST_ora_43619_20200913121607479069143795.aud
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
Build label:    RDBMS_12.2.0.1.0_LINUX.X64_170125
ORACLE_HOME:    /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1
System name:    Linux
Node name:      testserver
Release:        3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64
Version:        #1 SMP Fri Sep 21 09:07:21 UTC 2018
Machine:        x86_64
Instance name: DEVINST
Redo thread mounted by this instance: 1
Oracle process number: 55
Unix process pid: 43619, image: oracle@testserver (TNS V1-V3)
```

`Message` expected:

```
+00:00
LENGTH : '275'
ACTION :[7] 'CONNECT'
DATABASE USER:[1] '/'
PRIVILEGE :[6] 'SYSDBA'
CLIENT USER:[9] 'testuser'
CLIENT TERMINAL:[5] 'pts/0'
STATUS:[1] '0'
DBID:[10] '1762369616'
SESSIONID:[10] '4294967295'
USERHOST:[21] 'testserver'
CLIENT ADDRESS:[0] ''
ACTION NUMBER:[3] '100'
```

Due to these the fields werent parsed properly either.
What am I doing wrong? Why is it not parsing the message and the date correctly even though the debugger shows the right output?

**EDIT:**

As per baudsp suggestion I have overwritten my message like so:

```
filter {
  if [type] == "oracle" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "(?<day>[A-Za-z]{3})(\s*)(?<month>[A-Za-z]{3})(\s*)(?<monthday>[0-9]{1,2})(\s*)(?<hour>[0-9]{1,2}):(?<min>[0-9]{1,2}):(?<sec>[0-9]{2})(\s*)(?<year>[0-9]{4})(\s*)(?<message>[\S\s]*)" }
      overwrite => [ "message" ]
    }
.....
```

However Kibana is still showing me grokparse and dateparse errors :(

Thanks
J

Comment: For the Message `expected` part, as it seems you don't overwrite this field, it's not surprising that it's not the expected value.

Comment: For the first grok filter, the GREEDYDATA pattern translate to .*, which shouldn't match the newlines. To match the newlines, you can use `[\S\s]*`

Comment: Thanks for your comments baudsp, can you explain why Message has to be overwritten?

Comment: If you want to change the content of the `message` field (as it seems from your question you want to do it), you'd have to overwrite it